# Switching between arrays with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Right now I have 3 arrays I want to toggle between with my ng-repeat:

```
$scope.fooDataObj = {
array1:[{name:'john', id:'1'},{name:'jerry', id:'2'}],
array2[{name:'bill', id:'1'},{name:'tom', id:'2'}],
array3:[]
}
```

and my ng-repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in fooDataObj track by data.id"></li>
```

So all I want to do is dynamically switch between my arrays of data within my object in the most performant way.

So basically when some clicks `<button></button>`it will change from using `array1` in the `ng-repeat` to `array2`.

I've accomplished this by setting `ng-repeat="data in fooData"` then on click triggering `$scope.fooData = fooDataObj.array1`. But this is not very performant. Especially when switching between the populated arrays to the empty array.

Answer (score 1):

You could just switch the key and use bracket notation in the ng-repeat source.

```
 <li ng-repeat="data in fooDataObj[vm.source] track by data.id"></li>
```

and on button click set `vm.source` to text `array1, array2, array3`. If you want to make it dynamic derived keyname instead of hardcoding then just get the keys from the object as `Object.keys(fooDataObj)`

Comment: This works, thanks! but it still seems slow when removing the populated arrays elements from the dom.

Comment: Do you have a demo to show the slowness.. This is a very simple stuff accessing value of an object based on key. Slowness could be due to some other stuff that you are doing. Try to isolate the problem.